# Public string - cannot be resolved

Tags: java, arrays, string, try-catch, public

Error at

```
bw.write(dataString);
```

How can i fix this?
dataString cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test.txt"))) {
            String CurrLine;

            while((CurrLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(CurrLine);
            }
            String[] dataArray = new String[data.size()];
            String dataString = Arrays.toString(dataArray);

            String[] client = dataString.split("<::>");
            Integer nameId = Arrays.binarySearch(client, "Test");
            Integer versId = nameId + 1;
            System.out.println(client[nameId] + "\n" + client[versId]);


        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("FNFE");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOE");
        }
            try{
                File file = new File("src/test.txt");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(dataString);
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn about *scope* of variables. The scope of `dataString` is only confined to `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

Declare`dataString` outside of the try and catch block... Thats all. ;) If you declare it inside a loop or in this case your try catch block, its lifecycle is limited to it.

Like this:

```
String dataString = null;
```

and inside the try-catch block:

```
dataString = Arrays.toString(dataArray);
```

Comment: how can i get data from dataString?

Comment: Edited my answer with an example. The first line of code must be outside of the try-catch block

Comment: I got error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at test.main(test.java:33)

Comment: I bet its at this line: `System.out.println(client[nameId] + "\n" + client[versId]);`. Just debug and look up whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`dataString` is out of scope in the try block.

Perhaps add dataString as an instance variable at the top of your class.

```
public class test {
        private String dataString = null;
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test.txt"))) {
            String CurrLine;

            while((CurrLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(CurrLine);
            }
            String[] dataArray = new String[data.size()];
            dataString = Arrays.toString(dataArray);
         ...
```

Comment: I got error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at test.main(test.java:33)

Answer (score 0):

The dataString variable's scope is limited to the first try-catch block. Change its declaration as following,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String dataString = null;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test.txt"))) {
        String CurrLine;

        while((CurrLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data.add(CurrLine);
        }
        String[] dataArray = new String[data.size()];
        dataString = Arrays.toString(dataArray);

        String[] client = dataString.split("<::>");
        Integer nameId = Arrays.binarySearch(client, "Test");
        Integer versId = nameId + 1;
        System.out.println(client[nameId] + "\n" + client[versId]);


    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("FNFE");
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOE");
    }
    try{
        File file = new File("src/test.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(dataString);
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at test.main(test.java:33)

Comment: You might be searching for an element which does not exist in the array. The search returns -1 when there are no such items equal to the given one.

Comment: Also, according to the javadoc, the array must be sorted prior to calling the binary search. If not you have to do a linear search to find the index.

Comment: I have this element in my array. If i initialize dataString i got this error, if i remove code for write and initialize dataString in try-catch all works fine. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Debug and check at the line `Integer nameId = Arrays.binarySearch(client, "Test");` and make sure that the element is in the array and the array is sorted.